# How can I make an object inherit two objects in its prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to make an object inherit from two other objects but doing it like so does not work, how can I make it work?

```
function a() {

};

a.prototype.iamA = function() {
alert("a");
};  

function b() {

};

b.prototype.iamB = function() {
alert("b");
};

function ab() {

};

ab.prototype = new a();
ab.prototype = new b();

console.log(new ab());
```

It seems that the prototype is overridden how can I add to it, I have also tried adding it to the prototype but this doesn't work either?

Comment: That is impossible. In JS, an object can only inherit from one other object (or `null`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use object extension instead of assignment, e.g:

```
function extend(obj, source) {
    for (var prop in source) {
       obj[prop] = source[prop];
    }
    return obj;
}
```

then:

```
ab.prototype = extend(new a(), new b());         (1)
```

Or you may choose to use underscore's [extend function](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#extend).

```
ab.prototype = _.extend({}, new a(), new b());   (2)
```

**Edit**:

Strictly speaking, this is [mixin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) instead of real multi-inheritance, since
`(new ab instanceof b) === false` in both (1) and (2).

For more information, please take a look at this reference: [No multiple Inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model#No_multiple_inheritance).

That said, mixin is probably enough for you. It turns out that people who think
they need inheritance usually only need code reuse, not typing-related construction.
This is especially true for the [dynamic typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Dynamic_typing)(or [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)) language like JavaScript.

Comment: Note that this will neither `inst instanceof a` nor `inst instanceof b` allow to evaluate to true where `inst` is an instance of `ab`. Regardless, +1 since this is what I would have suggested. ;)

Comment: @alex23 First, although the OP mentioned `inherit`, mixin probably meets his need(People who insists inheritance usually only needs code reuse instead of typing-related construction). Secondly, I point out that my answer is not true multi-inheritance, which wouldn't mislead future visitors. Lastly, your answer is not multi-inheritance either(please see my comments on it).